# Counting Cycles - Intuition or formula

Tags: graph-theory

How many cycles of length 4 are there in K5?
My intuition is 5 (using 5 choose 4).
However, I know the answer is 15.
I'm trying to understand the intuition behind it.

Thanks!

Comment: Two cycles with the same vertices are not necessarily the same cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct as you can choose $4$ vertices in $\binom{5}{4}$ ways.
Further, for each there are $\dfrac{1}{2}(4-1)!$ [free circular permutations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html).